# SQL ERROR - Error sql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am getting an error that I dont know how to deal with.
I am running the same code without issue for another column but for this column it refuses to work.

```
SELECT * FROM Players WHERE Character = 'momo' // This one wont work

SELECT * FROM Players WHERE Class = 'Fighter' // this one works
```

Character is a VARCHAR and Class is TEXT. I have tried changing Character to TEXT and I still get the same issue. The value 'momo' exists in the table.

ERROR: Couldn't connect to server. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= ''' at line 1

Edit:
I am editing this incase someone find this and wants to know how it was fixed. User by the name of ueerdo Pointed out that I should use quotations and when I did, it worked. So I started looking into why it happened and I found out the SQL reserves Character for something else so it is something that I can't use unless it is in quotations.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Reserved word, methinks

Comment: What platform...?

Comment: @Danny should I change the name of the field? Because I have no issue updating that field, I just cant view it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I am running this code on a school server called php my admin

Comment: Probably depends on the platform, but SQL Server you could escape it in brackets `SELECT * FROM Players WHERE [Character] = 'momo'`

Comment: I tried that one

Comment: If it's MySQL then I think the escape character is a backtick `. These are just guesses without knowing which database you're using, however.

Comment: @Danny, you were right. Character was a reserved word. I ended up changing the word altogether. thanks!

Comment: @ZachLucas you didn't have to change the field name; you could've just delimited it with ` characters. It is a good practice to get into rather than memorizing reserved words and keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to delimit identifiers to prevent possible collision with reserved words and keywords.

```
SELECT * FROM `Players` WHERE `Character` = 'momo'
```